# iOS Banking AES-128 End to End Encryption Implementation

Tags: ios, azure, encryption, cryptography

I'm creating a banking application for iOS that is transferring sensitive encrypted data from an azure mobile backend to an iOS device. What is the best way to go about decrypting this data on an iOS device securely? What protocols should be used? What third party libraries / services? Are there standards for financial applications that I should be aware of?

I've heard things thrown around such as EKS encryption with SQL, SSL, RSA / Diffie Hellman encryption, AES-128 being a standard practice etc etc. Is there anything practical to implement without delving into low level C code?

Comment: If you are dealing with Credit Card payments you need to be aware of the PCI (Payment Card Industry) rules/requirements.

Comment: No credit card payments for now, but I'm looking for a decryption implementation that will simply work.

Comment: Use TLS and make sure to verify the server's certificate.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

My solution ended up being to use AESCrypt (github: https://github.com/Gurpartap/AESCrypt-ObjC)

This proved to be as simple as dragging the class files into XCode and calling

`[AESCrypt encrypt:secret password:password];
 [AESCrypt decrypt:secret password:password];`

Thanks for the help! I will probably end up implementing some sort of CocoaPods supported platform later on, but this will work for now.

Comment: 1) To encryption communication between a client and a server use SSL/TLS. Writing secure encrypted communication protocol from scratch is hard. 2) It's very unlikely that you managed to write anything secure using that library. For example you'll almost certainly suffer from a padding oracle. 3) If you really want to use AES with your own key management, Zaph's recommendation of RNCryptor looks much better than the library you chose.

Comment: @CodesInChaos what is a padding oracle?

Comment: @Unheilig When using unauthenticated encryption an attacker can often learn some information from how the recipient of a message reacts to an invalid message. This information can often be used to decrypt the whole message, one byte at a time. [Padding oracles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_oracle_attack) against CBC mode are a famous example.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This is currently a development prototype and going forward we will be using RNCryptor.

Comment: We will also be adding a layer of asymmetric encryption. Would it be better practice to encrypt the AES key with RSA? Sorry for my ignorance in cryptography. I'm a Sophomore in college interning as a Software Engineer at a bank and literally have not taken any of my CS courses yet.

Answer (score 1):

SSL works for data in transit, Pin the certificate.
AES128 is fine for data at rest but the key must be good and secured.

On iOS put the key Keychain, there is no more secure method.

If you need to store a key on a server that is more of a problem keeping it secure.

Finally at a minimum use two factor authentication on the server.

Comment: What would be the best implementation for decrypting an AES-128 encrypted string using a key stored in keychain?

Comment: I sugest [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor0), it handles many details that someone new to cryptographic security would miss.